# ListPlot3D with the color choosen from another list

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

I have a data set for doing a ListPlot3D in the required format as `data={{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}......{xN,yN,zN}}`. I also have another list with N values `V={v1,v2,....,vN}`. How do I do a ListPlot3D of `data` so that color of the points is taken from `V` and also the appropriate colorbar appears?

Comment: Please post your code to make reproduction/modification more comfortable.

Comment: There is the documented option [VertexColors](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html) for `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: @ybeltukov There is a documented option for vertex colours, but the output seems to be a partially shaded surface and doesn't have anything you might refer to as a point, so I wonder what the questioner is really seeking here.

Answer (score 3):

ListPlot3D usually produces a surface mesh , but you seem to want points as output. 
It is easy to produce those just using `Point`.

```
clrs = RGBColor /@ Sort@RandomReal[1, {50, 3}];
pts = Sort@RandomInteger[10, {50, 3}];
Show[Graphics3D@MapThread[{PointSize@Large, #2, Point[#1]} &, {pts, clrs}],Axes->True]
```

[image]